# Converting a qt project into a reusable library

Tags: qt, qt4

I have one qt project(containing .h,.cpp,.ui files) which i want to convert into a reusable library which can be used in any other qt project simply by adding it (just like we add header files).

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this thread:[Qt widget in dll](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17255-dll-using-qt)
The project is in the attachment for you to study all the kinks.