# Creating a C++ library from existing source code in QT creator

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, qt-creator, dllexport

I have been coding C++ for a while now and I use Qt creator as the development tool.
Recently I created a Non-QT project and did all the C++ coding and the application worked fine as expected.
It has around 20 classes both .h and .cpp files.

Now the real question.
I want to create a library of the application so that my work can be used in other applications built on top of the same.

In Java, creating a library(Jar file ) is hassle free,In case of eclipse IDE we just need go to the project and export a Jar file. Period!

How do I do the same for a C++ project in QT creator?

I went through some online tutorials but these suggest to create a new C++ library project!
I did try  that way but thats an altogether different project.
My source code is outside that library project.
So how will my code be part of the same?
Do I need to copy paste all my code into the library project?

Also, once created, How to use the library modules in calling programs?

As suggested, I am pasting the contents of the .pro file below(Actual class names have been changed)

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    a.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    b.cpp \
    c.cpp \
    d.cpp 

HEADERS += \
    X.h \
    a.h \
    b.h \
    c.h \
    d.h
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a qt project into a reusable library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726418/converting-a-qt-project-into-a-reusable-library)

Comment: With a few tweaks to your QMake or CMake file, your project can be imported as a library in other projects. You simply need to expose a part of your codebase as a library for others to use. I suggest pasting your QMake (.pro) or CMakeLists.txt file into your question text and people can tell you how to modify it.

Comment: I have added the .pro file contents